# JSON communication issue with ROS2 deserializeJson() returned InvalidInput

Tags: ros2, arduino, ros-humble, json-prolog, platform

Currently I am working on mobile robot, I am using MicroROS ESP32 and Arduino Mega ((## Not that MicroROS does not support Arduino mega board yet##)) . I am using the ESP32 to publish and subscribe to ROS topics. The mega will handle these to move the robot.
Based on serial communication and I have found that Arduino JSON technique is easier to send data between devices.

I am sending from the esp32 just only /cmd_vel

The problem only with serial communication some times it runs for few seconds an then it just keep giving this error message (deserializeJson() returned InvalidInput):

[image]

for my Arduino mega I have modified "linorobot" from github to fit my needs. here is the main loop and the receiving function:

```
void loop()
{
static unsigned long prev_control_time = 0;
static unsigned long prev_imu_time = 0;
static unsigned long prev_send_receive_time = 0;
static unsigned long prev_debug_time = 0;
static bool imu_is_initialized;
//this block drives the robot based on defined rate
if ((millis() - prev_control_time) >= (1000 / COMMAND_RATE))
{
moveBase();
prev_control_time = millis();
}
//this block stops the motor when no command is received
if ((millis() - g_prev_command_time) >= 400)
{
stopBase();
}

//this block publishes the IMU data based on defined rate
if ((millis() - prev_imu_time) >= (1000 / IMU_PUBLISH_RATE))
{
// Sanity check if the IMU is connected
if (!imu_is_initialized)
{
imu_is_initialized = initIMU();
if (imu_is_initialized)
Serial.println("IMU Initialized");
else
Serial.println("IMU failed to initialize. Check your IMU connection.");
}
else
{
// Publish IMU data directly over the serial port
PubImu();
}
prev_imu_time = millis();
}
if((millis() - prev_send_receive_time) >= 1000 / S_R_RATE)
{
msgReceiver();
prev_send_receive_time = millis();
}
}

void msgReceiver(){
if (Serial2.available())
{
// Allocate the JSON document
// This one must be bigger than the sender's because it must store the strings
StaticJsonDocument<1000> msgR;
// Read the JSON document from the "link" serial port
DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(msgR, Serial2);
if (err == DeserializationError::Ok)
{
// save values in local variable
// (we must use as<T>() to resolve the ambiguity)
g_req_linear_vel_x = msgR["twist_msg_linear_x"].as<float>();
g_req_angular_vel_z = msgR["twist_msg_angular_z"].as<float>();

}
else
{
// Print error to the "debug" serial port
Serial.print("deserializeJson() returned ");
Serial.println(err.c_str());

// Flush all bytes in the "link" serial port buffer
while (Serial2.available() > 0)
Serial2.read();
}
}
}
```

This is my esp32 code but not including subscribers where no issue in that, I can print the message correctly:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "ros_communication.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#define S_R_RATE 5 //hz
RosCommunication ros_communication;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
ros_communication.initialize();
ros_communication.subscriber_define();
ros_communication.executors_start();
}
void loop() {
ros_communication.start_receiving_msgs();
// Access g_req_vel_x and g_req_angular_z
float vel_x = RosCommunication::g_req_vel_x;
float angular_z = RosCommunication::g_req_angular_z;
// Use vel_x and angular_z as needed in your main code
// For example, you can print them to Serial Monitor
// Serial.print("g_req_vel_x: ");
// Serial.println(vel_x);
// Serial.print("g_req_angular_z: ");
// Serial.println(angular_z);
float prev_send_receive_time = 0;
if((millis() - prev_send_receive_time) >= 1000 / S_R_RATE)
{
//Start sending Velocity commands to our robot
//
// Create the JSON document
StaticJsonDocument<1000> msgS;
//IMU msgs
msgS["twist_msg_linear_x"] = vel_x;
msgS["twist_msg_angular_z"] = angular_z;
// Send the JSON document over the "link" serial port
serializeJson(msgS, Serial2);
prev_send_receive_time = millis();
}
}
```

Does any have any idea of whats wrong?

#Arduino #platformio #ROS2 #humble #ROS2_humble #ROS #JSON #JSONserialization